# Is there a Unix command to record changes to output of another command?

Tags: command-line, unix, watch

I have a long running operation that affects some state.
That state is shown by running a certain command, say `showst`.

I want to see have a log of all the possible outputs `showst` will display during that long running operation.

For a short operation I would use

```
watch -n0.1 showst
```

And would just stare at the terminal looking at what is going on.
But if the operation runs for an hour that is not very practical.
I want to have a log that would tell me that at a specific time `showst` output changed to this.  And then it changed to that.

Is there a command that can help me?

---

*Edit to add a bit of clarification.*

Here is a specific example of what I would like to see.  Let's say that the operation runs for an hour.  `showst` outputs `A` for the first half an hour, then `B` for 10 minutes, then switches to `A` again.

I want to see a log similar to this:

```
2016-08-19 12:00: A
2016-08-19 12:30: B
2016-08-19 12:40: A
```

It would be great if `A` and `B` could be multiline as well.

It is kind of like what `watch --differences` can do on a terminal, if you are sitting and watching, but I want that in a log.

Comment: does it output to STDOUT?  You could try showst >log.txt &  on the next line you could tail -f log.txt or grep the file or anything.

Comment: The output is to stdout, but the command outputs current state and the exits.  If I run 'showst >log.txt' I would get just the current state.  I want to see all the possible states over a period of time.  I want identical outputs "folded" and only when something in the output changes I want to see new entry in the log.

Comment: showst >>log.txt is appending.  cat log.txt|sort --unique  hides and sorts.

Comment: Appending is not helpful on it's own if 'showst' exist after it outputs current state.  And if I run it in a loop, over a log period of time I would have multiple identical entries.  I would not want that.  I want to see when the output changed.  Similar to 'watch --differences' but in a log, instead of on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a dedicated command, but I would have written something like that:

```
(while true; do sleep 0.1; showst; done) | uniq
```

*Note: sleep implementations on Linux usually supports such floating arguments, but if you need a portable solution then you should use an integer argument there which limit the pooling to one second tick, or no sleep at all which will use your cpu a lot.*

See also man pages of [sleep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sleep) and [uniq](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq).

Comment: This only works if the 'showst' output is one line.  And it does not tell me when the change occurred.  I would not see the sequence of changes.  If the state changes from A to B and then to A again, I would only have 'A' and 'B' in the output.

Comment: As said by @drewbenn and by the man page, `uniq` prints the first occurrence of any new series as soon as it comes and ignores consecutive duplicates. You can `|grep` the showst call to extract wanted line or words and you can append `|while read NEW_STATE; do echo "$(date) - ${NEW_STATE}"; done` to prepend dates of detected changes on the result.